# Re-phrasing help

Tags: technique

'The glass filled with water slipped from Kekibhoys's hand while he was lost in his thoughts.'

This is the opening sentence to a short story that three of us are collaborating on. I feel this sentence does not draw the reader into the story and it seems a bit off.

I wish to convey the same idea but want it to be re-worded. Any help?

PS: The story is fantasy woven in real life, if that helps.

Comment: Hi pappuyaar! I'm afraid requests to rephrase one particular snippet are off-topic here - here's [some detail on our rephrase-request policy](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/a/717/1046). Getting a question or two closed is par for the course on Stack Exchange, so don't worry about it - and if other questions coming up during your collaboration meet our guidelines - please share them with us! :D

Comment: Thanks Standback! I should have gone through the Meta site first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think re-wording won't be enough. A character dropping a glass of water because he/she's spacing out, is not exactly what I would call intriguing.

I suggest something like this:

> The glass of water slipped from Kekibhoys' hand as he saw the giant blood
>   stain on his wall.

or

> Kekibhoys' glass of water fell on the floor as he saw the giant blood
>   stain on his wall.

This is just an example, of course. It all depends on what your story is about.